# valueForKey only returns memory address and not actually value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsinteger, memory-address

```
    NSDictionary *topic = [spaces objectAtIndex:i];
    NSInteger topicid = [topic valueForKey:@"TOPICID"];
```

when I run this and print out topic I get the following:

```
Printing description of topic:
<CFDictionary 0xdb2a70 [0x30307a00]>{type = mutable, count = 2, capacity = 12, pairs = (
    10 : <CFString 0xdb5300 [0x30307a00]>{contents = "TOPICID"} = 29
    12 : <CFString 0xdb53a0 [0x30307a00]>{contents = "TOPICNAME"} = <CFString 0xdb5360 [0x30307a00]>{contents = "zzzzzzzz"}
)}
```

However, when I look at topicid, the value is always a memory address. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the code of how you're setting the objects in spaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe the value is actually an NSNumber. You would get this using:

```
NSInteger topicid = [[topic objectForKey:@"TOPICID"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries can only contain objects, not primitives. Whatever is stored in there (as Xetius suggested) is probably wrapped in some form. It would appear that TOPICID is an NSString.

Comment: doesn't the description output indicate that the key is a string and the value is simply 29 (no type defined)?

Comment: The description is 'pretty printed'; there's no way to store a raw integer in a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

In the array output, you can see topicID is a string value (NSString).  So, you would want to set it as Xetius describes - but not because it is an NSNumber, because NSString has an "intValue" method.